# my roc curve is always perfect and my precision is always 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, dlib, roc, precision-recall

I am working on deep learning recently, using my trained dlib model to predict landmarks on some picture. Like my last question said, I have two point sets, one is true landmark(from `xml`), the other is predicted landmark(from `dlib` way).
I use sklearn `roc_curve` and `precision_recall_cure` to plot curve, and the y_test is a binary set that is 1 if the nomarlized distance(distance between predicted landmark and true landmark divide by two eyes distance in true landmark) < 0.10, the y_socre is a set of float numbers which is 1 - normalized distance.
I plot ROC curve and PR curve based on this data, but the roc curve is always perfect(from (0,0) to (1,0) to (1,1)) and precision is always 1(PR curve is a horizontal line).
Here are roc curve.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hydt.png)
I am really confused. The following is my code.

```
    import *
    root = et.parse("***/training_with_face_landmarks.xml").getroot()
    images = {}
    for ima in root.find('images').findall('image'):
         images[ima.attrib['file']] = ima.find('box').attrib
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('sp.dat')
    alllandmark = {}
    for i in images:
        img_mat = cv2.imread('dogs/' + i)
        alllandmark[i] = predictor(img_mat,dlib.rectangle(int(images[i]['left']),int(images[i]['top']),int(images[i]['left'])+int(images[i]['width']),int(images[i]['top'])+int(images[i]['height'])))
    truelandmark = {}
    for ima in root.find('images').findall('image'):
         temp = []
         for part_im in ima.find('box').findall('part'):
            temp.append(dlib.point(int(part_im.attrib['x']), int(part_im.attrib['y'])))
         truelandmark[ima.attrib['file']] = temp
    score_temp = []
    temp = []
    for name in truelandmark:
        stand = ((truelandmark[name][1].x - truelandmark[name][5].x) ** 2 + (truelandmark[name][1].y - truelandmark[name][5].y)**2)**0.5
        differ = ((truelandmark[name][1].x - alllandmark[name].part(1).x) ** 2 + (truelandmark[name][1].y - alllandmark[name].part(1).y)**2)**0.5
        score_temp.append(1-differ/stand)
        if rate < 0.10:
            temp.append(1)
        else:
            temp.append(0)
    y_test = np.array(temp)
    y_score = np.array(score_temp)
    fpr, tpr, thr = roc_curve(y_test, y_score, pos_label=1)
    auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_score)
    then plot...
```

To be honest, I have some idea about it. Maybe the curve is actually perfect because of choosing y_score and y_test. In my strategy, they are strongly related(if y_score[x] > 0.9, y_test[x] = 1). So maybe my way to plot roc curve is totally wrong. I had added random float numbers between 0 and 0.04 to y_score once so the roc curve looks more normal. In my opinion, because I always add float numbers between 0 and 0.04, the added numbers can be minused when I compare two algorithm. I told my teacher, he think it is not right.
The PR curve is the same.
So, did I choose wrong `y_test`, or `y_score`? Or I did something wrong in early stage?

Comment: Can you do some tests where you replace `x` with random data? `y` with random data to confirm that you can even create a problem that does not learn? After that it will be clearer what next steps are.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand clearly. Do you mean I should create some fake random landmark points as predicted ones, or make some random score(the second argument of `roc_curve`), or the `y_test`(the first argument of `roc_curve`) should be random?

Comment: Yes, demonstrate that your code can produce non perfect scores with unlearnable data.

Comment: a) make x random, b) make only y random. Either should be enough to break it.

Comment: Unless your y does not depend on x in any way (and is basically constant).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will have a try

Comment: Did you post the full code you used? From what I see, the error is quite clear.

Comment: yes, that's all my code. I am quite a green hand about deep learning, i really do not know why it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is a theoretical error in the way you pose the problem (and the code by implication). According to what you wrote:

> `y_test` is a binary set that is 1 if the normalized distance (distance between predicted landmark and true landmark divide by two eyes distance in true landmark) < 0.10

By principle, you are considering `y_test` as a variable directly dependent on prediction, which is a methodological contradiction.

In fact, `y_test` has to be a list of true binary labels per se. It is somehow "truth" by itself and has not to be dependent on how (well) you are able to predict.

The goal of classification/regression is to get prediction close to truth, NOT truth close to prediction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always suspect that my understanding of the whole algorithm is wrong, and now you clearly show it. I will try to find out another way to plot roc curve.

Comment: Please note that the conceptual mistake is related to how you consider and treat "truth", not to how you plot a curve.